# Building Tensorflow Lite for Linux x86_64 using bazel

Tags: linux, build, bazel, tensorflow-lite

As the title says im trying to build TFLite(R2.2) for Linux x86_64, i already have it working for Macosx x86_64, but i cant seem to find any options within the bazel build configs to change the build for linux.

I configure the bazel build by using ./configure and setting all the properties correctly, then use

bazel build  //tensorflow/lite/java:libtensorflowlite_jni.so to build the .so

But no matter what options i pass into --config it always builds the .so for the host architecture (Macosx)

If anyone knows how to do this would be grand.

Answer (score 0):

[This Reference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36178#issuecomment-634150344)  answers your solution and for linux [follow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36178#issuecomment-634150344)